# Mysql SQL for "replace everything but this" where xxx

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, date, view

I've got a terrible database on a project and they've used a text field for dates.

So, I need to build a view that has only the year in one column. The problem is that I have dates with any standard format like:

- 01-01-2012
- 01.01.2012
- 01 01 2012
- 1/1/2012
- 01/2012
- 1/2012
- 2012
- 01.2012

Is there any way to build an SQL (MySQL) to get only those 4 year digits to build a view?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Wow I bet this project has some other nice "surprises" just waiting for you.

Comment: It's surprising they didn't just put all of the columns into a huge comma delimited string and store it in one column <- that was a joke before anyone picks me up on it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the whole data structure, you can use REGEX or [String functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right).

For example, with your sample data the last 4 digits on the right are the year so using

```
SELECT RIGHT(fieldname, 4) FROM table
```

would work.  If that pattern doesn't work then you've either got to use concat and start splitting them or write a REGEX statement.

If RIGHT will work then you can do an INSERT SELECT

```
INSERT INTO table (yearcolumn)
SELECT RIGHT(fieldname, 4) FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) matching, to get rows from given year. There's no way to get a capture from regular expression though.
However, if the year part is alwayst last 4 digits, use [`RIGHT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_right). Otherwise, you will need to do reformatting client-side.

Comment: Thanks, I've been able to search without problems using regexp, but I need the actual year for ordering and grouping. Maybe RIGHT() will work, let me try!

Comment: RIGHT() does the trick, at least they've put the year at the end in every row ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may also help. This is Oracle query for the whole current year. It can be easily converted to any SQL. It uses recursive query to build annual table. Replace SYSDATE and Oracle formats with your version of SQL formats and system date:

```
WITH data(r, start_date) AS 
(
 SELECT 1 r, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') start_date FROM dual -- start_date: 1/1/2013
  UNION ALL
 SELECT r+1, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR')+r-1 FROM data WHERE r < 365 -- any number: end_date - start_date or get the number of days in your year your way...
)
SELECT start_date
     , TO_CHAR(start_date, 'YYYY')              curr_year  
     , TRUNC(start_date, 'IW')                  wk_starts   
     , TRUNC(start_date, 'IW') + 7 - 1/86400    wk_ends
     , TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (start_date, 'IW'))   ISO_wk# 
 FROM data
/

START_DATE    CURR_YEAR    WK_STARTS    WK_ENDS                 ISO_WK#
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1/2013      2013        12/31/2012    1/6/2013 11:59:59 PM      1
1/1/2013      2013        12/31/2012    1/6/2013 11:59:59 PM      1
...
12/28/2013    2013        12/23/2013    12/29/2013 11:59:59 PM    52
12/29/2013    2013        12/23/2013    12/29/2013 11:59:59 PM    52
12/30/2013    2013        12/30/2013    1/5/2014 11:59:59 PM      1
```